# link text box in Swift

Tags: swift, textbox

Is it possible to link text boxes in Swift? For example, I have two text boxes that the user can type in. When the user has filled up the first text box (--i.e. there's no more room for text) the cursor automatically moves to the second text box so any further characters typed will appear in the second text box.

Comment: Yes, it's definitely possible, but what have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `becomeFirstResponder` method from the textfield:

```
//This textfield will get the focus.
yourNextTextField.becomeFirstResponder()
```

To check the number of letters in your UITextfield, you can implement the `UITextFieldDelegate` and use the [`shouldChangeCharactersInRange`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITextFieldDelegate/textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:) method.

In there you calculate the length of your string.